# C beginner - Hello World program not doing anything on Windows from command prompt

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, command-prompt

I'm about to start learning C (I need to program something in C, to convert it into MIPS later).

I'm on Windows 8, and downloaded MinGW and set the path variable to its directory, so that the gcc or g++ commands should work in command prompt.

I copied the following Hello World example into a .c text file.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{ // This is a comment
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

However, although I'm in the correct directory as the file, on command prompt when I type "gcc helloWorld.c" it pauses for a couple of seconds, and then doesn't do anything. It just acts as if the program has finished and allows me to type something else in.

This is likely to be a simple mistake - I don't really understand what I'm doing. But can anyone help me out?

Comment: You need 2 // for a comment! like this: // This is a comment

Comment: Comment should be either `//` or `/*.......*/`

Comment: "then doesn't do anything". It should give a compiler error. This sounds like you haven't set up mingw properly.

Comment: I think there is some configuration issue else you should have get errors.

Comment: Check if you have set the `PATH` environment variable correctly.

Comment: @Wolff: On command prompt just type `gcc` and tell us what message you got

Comment: I put the directory for the PATH variable after a ;, since it already had one for Java in there. The thing is, it recognises when I type an non-existent file or invalid file type. It just doesn't seem to do anything with the code in the actual .c file.

Comment: @1336087 When just typing gcc I got...

gcc: fatal error: no input files
compiliation terminated.

Comment: @Wolff Type this in your command lines: `gcc -v` and show us the message

Answer (score 9):

When you issue the gcc command you are actually COMPILING the source code, not RUNNING the program.
The Compilation process creates an executable file to that you can run.

In the example by previous poster:

> gcc -o helloWorld helloWorld.c

The -o parameter is the [o]utput name of the executable file to be created, let say "helloworld.exe" (as you are using Windows).
This should create a new file helloworld.exe, Now you can RUN that file.

You should read a little bit more on general C programming and compiling.

Comment: Oh I get it. So in other words, you can't use the command prompt to run the program directly from the file, like you can with Python and Java? I noticed it created a .exe file and typing helloWorld.exe into the prompt printed the words in the window.

Comment: @Wolf : C is a *compiled* language, and a compiler generates stand-alone native code executables. You can run the generated executable *without* the compiler being installed on the computer.  Python (in interpreted language) and Java (a VM laguage) both require runtime support (the interpreter and the JVM respectively).

Comment: @Wolff You have to create an `exe` file with `gcc` which you can then immediately run.

Comment: C, C++, pascal among other languages are Compiled, means COMPILE the source code to a native code that then you can run.
Python, TCL, ruby are Interpreted,  means that they are read line by line and executed line by line. Java , C# are kind of hibrid.

Comment: If you want a compiler that immediately runs your program, check out [tcc](http://bellard.org/tcc/), the tiny C compiler. It's probably not what you need though.

Answer (score 4):

You can write comments with `//` or `/* ... */`

Also to compile a c program with gcc use this:

```
gcc -o helloWorld helloWorld.c
```

So this should work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{  // This is a comment
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The single / was a typo sorry. I think it got lost when I was formatting it as code on here. There were two in the code. I removed the comment altogether, and used your command, but it still didn't do anything.

Comment: Then i would do what user1336087 said! just type gcc and show us the message.

Comment: I replied to 1336087's post with the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use:

```
gcc -o *executablename* *filename.c*
```

which creates an executable file called *executablename* or use:

```
gcc *filename.c*
```

which will make an executable file with the default name (a.out for UNIX, I'm not sure what it is for Windows). If you look into the directory, you should be able to see this executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
gcc helloWorld.c
```

and after that:

```
./a.out
```